# Turn on a point using the DWA local planner with a differentially-driven car

Tags: ros-melodic, dwa

How can DWA be used to let a diff-car turn around at specific point?

For example,
[image]

If the goal is at point (1), I want the car to turn first, then follow the line, like the green line in the pic.
The fact is, when I use dwa, it instead follows the yellow line: it goes forward and turns to reach the path.

So, how can DWA be configured to follow the green line?

Comment: Add more context and information about your use case. I would divide the long path between the signal points and use a simple PID controller that will be called at the end of the partial paths at signal points, which will rotate the robot in place until its front is +- straight to the next point. Then use DWA again to move the robot.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the DWA planner is projecting a series of potential trajectories in front if it and finding which is the most suitable to advance and turn. "Most suitable" is calculated by projecting a point forward and finding the predicted error, with a lower error trajectory being better. In practice, as you've observed, this can produce behaviors where the robot must go forward slightly to turn. However, some robots (like yours), have the ability to turn in place. For this reason, DWA provides the ability to change the distance of the point that is being projected.

Per the [documentation on DWA](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner), this parameter is:

```
~<name>/forward_point_distance (double, default: 0.325)
    The distance from the center point of the robot to
    place an additional scoring point, in meters
```

Set this parameter value to 0. This will enable turn-in-place trajectories to be produced.